# Send model instance from controller to view and send same model instance back to controller using ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am sending a model object to a strongly typed view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   ReportModel model = new ReportModel();
   return View(model);
}
```

I want the view to send back the same model instance back to another ActionMethod using ajax in jquery.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Report/getPT',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
             model:'@Model'
        }
```

This is the ActionMethod that receives the same model instance.

```
public ActionResult getPT(ReportModel model){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you wish to do with the model on the server, and what you wish to return.
Do you wish to return a partial view or just something indicating how the submission went?

You have several options.

You can send the model using Ajax form

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("getPT", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod="POST", UpdateTargetId = "UpdateContainer" }))
{
    <!-- FORM elements goes here... -->
}
```

in your view, place

```
<div id="UpdateContainer"></div>
```

Where you want to render the partial view

Instead of returning ActionResult, set the action to return `PartialViewResult`

```
public PartialViewResult getPT(ReportModel repModel)
{
    // instantiate a viewmodel
    var model = new YourViewModel();
    return PartialView("YourPartial", model);
}
```

Or, if you don't need it to return a partial view, maybe you just need to know how the submission went, you can send it with jQuery, like you are attempting in your code, to a WEB API controller

```
public class ApiTestController : ApiController
{
    public bool getPT(ReportModel model)
    {
        // do the work with your model
        return ..... whatever ? :)
    }
}
```